# What are the risks of Storing Credit Card / Bank Account Information in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, security, local-storage

I recently noticed a bill pay website I was using seemed to be storing my bank account and credit card number in my browser's LocalStorage. The data is stored in JSON object that gets stringified into LocalStroage. There is no special encoding, obfuscation, or encryption of the data.

While this was very off-putting initially and definitely seems like a substandard engineering practice, I'm having trouble thinking of ways this implementation could be meaningfully hacked:

- Since the site was HTTPS, a man-in-the-middle attack could not inject
  malicious JavaScript to read out of LocalStorage.
- LocalStorage is not
  shared on the same domain between HTTP and HTTPS, so that would rule
  out script injection over non-SSL connections.
- If the web app failed to sanitize user-submitted content, perhaps a malicious script could be injected to steal data from LocalStorage, but it could also steal this data from JavaScript's memory directly. Thus, the risk level is no different using LocalStorage.
- A malicious browser plugin could perhaps read the data out of LocalStorage, but that's really no different from the risk that a malicious plugin could scrape the data off the web page or read it from JavaScript memory.
- If the user logged into this site on a public computer, it's plausible someone could steal their payment data out of LocalStorage. But that wouldn't be too different than someone stealing their data off the screen had they left themselves logged into the application. I'm assuming that LocalStorage gets cleared upon log out (which might be an overly generous assumption here).

What other security vulnerabilities are opened up by this practice?

Comment: This is a good question. However, I'm also curious myself what vulnerabilities this might open up. Due case point, I'm building an application right now and I have been noticing a lot of websites are storing login credentials such as the user's email, username and password with a hash algorithm in local storage. I've read up on this and a lot of people have said to a mix between cookies and local storage but I myself am also looking for a preferred standard.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by local storage getting cleared upon logout.  The browser does not do it automatically.  Are you suggesting that the developer wrote code to clear it?  Usually they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the web app failed to sanitize user-submitted content, perhaps a
>   malicious script could be injected to steal data from LocalStorage,
>   but it could also steal this data from JavaScript's memory directly.
>   Thus, the risk level is no different using LocalStorage.

I disagree. It makes a big difference if a script has to be injected into a very specific web page to be able to get access to user entered sensitive data or if the JavaScript can be injected on any page on that host and simply access the LocalStorage and send the data somewhere. In the latter case one page that is accessed by the user at any point is sufficient for the attack.

Furthermore you have to take into account that the LocalStorage is usually stored in plain text by the web browser.

IMHO the only way to store sensitive data in the LocalStorage is to let the server encrypt it using an authenticated cipher using a user-specific key that is only known by the server. If afterwards the data should be used again, the client could sent it to the server and the server can the decrypt it and use it. Of course the sensitive part should never ever be sent back to the client (e.g. as pre-filled form on a web page).